# Array reorder based on matching values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

Array reorder based on matching values

Array order should change based on user search , matching objects come first

```
let movies = [{
    "MovNameOne": ["comedy", "fun", "2021"]
  },
  {
    "MovNameTwo": ["thriller", "suspense", "2022"]
  },
  {
    "MovNameThree": ["thriller", "comedy", "2021"]
  },
  {
    "MovNameFour": ["action", "mixed", "2000"]
  },
  {
    "MovNameFive": ["fun", "mixed", "2021"]
  },
];

 console.log( movies.sort( () =>  ****  );
```

If user knows exact full name of movie then this matching object should come first and user can search based on random keywords

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the Levenshtein distance between strings and sort them accordingly.

[source code for Leventshtein distance taken from here](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/js/s/levenshtein-distance/)

[Levenshtein distance wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#:%7E:text=Informally%2C%20the%20Levenshtein%20distance%20between,considered%20this%20distance%20in%201965.)

```js
const levenshteinDistance = (s, t) => {
    if (!s.length) return t.length;
    if (!t.length) return s.length;
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= t.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = [i];
        for (let j = 1; j <= s.length; j++) {
            arr[i][j] =
                i === 0
                    ? j
                    : Math.min(
                        arr[i - 1][j] + 1,
                        arr[i][j - 1] + 1,
                        arr[i - 1][j - 1] + (s[j - 1] === t[i - 1] ? 0 : 1)
                    );
        }
    }
    return arr[t.length][s.length];
};

let movies = [{
    "MovNameOne": ["comedy", "fun", "2021"]
},
{
    "MovNameTwo": ["thriller", "suspense", "2022"]
},
{
    "MovNameThree": ["thriller", "comedy", "2021"]
},
{
    "MovNameFour": ["action", "mixed", "2000"]
},
{
    "MovNameFive": ["fun", "mixed", "2021"]
},
];


// a series of test input to check the function

let testInputs = ["MovNameF", "MovN", "MovNameOne", "MovNameFour"];

testInputs.forEach(inp => {
// if levenshtein distance between input and element a is greater than input and element b then sort a after be else sort b after a
// > 0 means sort a after b
// < 0 means sort b after a
    console.log(inp, movies.sort((a, b) => levenshteinDistance(inp, Object.keys(a)[0]) > levenshteinDistance(inp, Object.keys(b)[0]) ? 1 : -1))
})
```

You can use the same logic on the movie genre/keyword to sort them accordingly

Comment: When I tested with let testInputs = ["fun"]; , In result  "MovNameOne", "MovNameFive" should come first @AnanthDev , thanks for your support

Comment: that's because in the code im only comparing names, i wrote this to give you an idea on how to accomplish it